# JavaFX java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException while executing Java class

Tags: javafx, netbeans, invocationtargetexception

I'm trying to test a program to Log in or register a person. But I keep getting the same Exception.(InvocationTargetException) :

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:465)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1081)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3324)
    at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3287)
    at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3255)
    at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3227)
    at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3203)
    at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3196)
    at librarymanagement.FXMain.start(FXMain.java:22)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application librarymanagement.FXMain
```

FXML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIconView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="469.0" prefWidth="691.0" styleClass="login-form" stylesheets="@designLogin.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane layoutX="102.0" layoutY="63.0" prefHeight="344.0" prefWidth="487.0" styleClass="card-form" stylesheets="@designLogin.css">
         <children>
            <FontAwesomeIconView fill="WHITE" glyphName="USERS" layoutX="209.0" layoutY="78.0" selectionFill="#f29eec" size="5em" text="" />
            <Label layoutX="207.0" layoutY="102.0" text="Login" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Berlin Sans FB" size="30.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <TextField layoutX="152.0" layoutY="159.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="180.0" promptText="Student Id" styleClass="textfield" stylesheets="@designLogin.css" />
            <PasswordField layoutX="151.0" layoutY="194.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="180.0" promptText="Password" styleClass="textfield" stylesheets="@designLogin.css" />
            <Button layoutX="214.0" layoutY="242.0" mnemonicParsing="false" styleClass="login-btn" stylesheets="@designLogin.css" text="Signup" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <Button layoutX="617.0" layoutY="51.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="25.0" styleClass="close" stylesheets="@designLogin.css" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="2.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="2.0">
         <graphic>
            <FontAwesomeIconView fill="WHITE" glyphName="CLOSE" size="1.2em" text="" textAlignment="CENTER" wrappingWidth="15.980972915887833" />
         </graphic>
      </Button>
      <Button layoutX="624.0" layoutY="2.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="32.0" styleClass="minimize" stylesheets="@designLogin.css">
         <graphic>
            <FontAwesomeIconView fill="WHITE" glyphName="MINUS" textAlignment="CENTER" wrappingWidth="16.095197677612305" />
         </graphic>
      </Button>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

CSS File:
/*
Created on : 13 janv. 2023, 20:47:39
Author     : chahrazed.benazaiez
*/

```
.login-form{
    -fx-background-color:linear-gradient(to bottom right, #2a2438, #352f44);
}

.card-form{
    -fx-background-color:#5c5470;
    -fx-background-radius:15px;
}

.close{
    -fx-background-color:transparent;
    -fx-cursor:hand;
}

.close:hover{
    -fx-background-color:#dbd8e3;
}

.minimize{
    -fx-background-color:transparent;
    -fx-cursor:hand;
}

.minimize:hover{
    -fx-background-color:#dbd8e3;
}

.textfield{
    -fx-background-color:transparent;
    -fx-text-inner-color:#fff;
    -fx-border-color:#fff;
    -fx-border-width:0px 0px .4px 0px;
    -fx-font-size:13px;
}

.textfield:focused{
    -fx-border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px;
}

.login-btn{
    -fx-background-color:#dbd8e3;
    -fx-background-radius:15px;
    -fx-cursor:hand;
    -fx-font-size:15px;
}

.login-btn:hover{
    -fx-background-color:#ffe9e3;
}
```

I couldn't find where the issue is. Can anyone help me out, please? (Thanks in advance ^^)

I am expecting the Login Window to appear conveniently.

Comment: Unrelated to your error: I recommend [Ikonli](https://kordamp.org/ikonli/) rather than fontawesome as Ikonli is more comprehensive, better documented, and better maintained.

Comment: Thank you @jewelsea for the alternative ^^